# XCode archive phonegap clang error 254

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, xcode5

I am developing phonegap app for ios. So far I've been successfuly archiving app inside XCode but today when I press archive I got compile error and this error message:

```
PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT:
Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/vg/zd7k0cs933774p44qtb7vmy00000gn/T/CDVViewController-a16940.m
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/vg/zd7k0cs933774p44qtb7vmy00000gn/T/CDVViewController-a16940.sh
clang: note: diagnostic msg:

************
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 254
```

I can't build revision that I build day before so there should be problem in source code.

- Product -> Run (simulator) : WORKS
- Product -> Build For -> Testing : WORKS
- Product -> Build For -> Running : WORKS
- Product -> Build For -> Profiling : ERROR
- Product -> Archive : ERROR

XCode 5.1.1
Phonegap 3.5.0-0.21.14
Cordova 3.5.0-0.2.7

Answer (score 1):

try to use this steps

1. Select your Project icon.
2. Choose Build Settings.
3. For “Architectures”, select $ARCHS_STANDARD – Standard architectures (armv7, armv7s, arm64)
4. For “Valid Architectures”, add “arm64″
5. Select your CordovaLib.xcodeproj icon
6. In the Build Settings for the Project (not Target), delete *all* the conditional architecture settings (hover to see the minus sign). This is what is recommended by Apple in their Xcode 5.1 Release Notes.
7. For “Architectures”, select $ARCHS_STANDARD – Standard architectures (armv7, armv7s, arm64)
8. For “Valid Architectures”, 
   Find Valid Architectures in it.

   Just double click on that and remove armv64 from that.

   Make sure there is armv7 and armv7s only.

   In my case this worked for me.
9. now do it for “Target“

Comment: Unfortunately this didnt changed anything. In simulator it works fine but archive fails.

Comment: you are doing something wrong . may be please go step by step .